# Why is the measured year 2018 inflation rate low despite rounds of quantitative easing?

Tags: inflation, monetary-policy

Is it correct to state year 2018 inflation rate of 2.2% is very low? Is it correct to state that even though the commodity prices have not increased, the increased money supply coming from the numerous rounds of quantitative easing found its way into the stock market and the bull market in the past few years were fueled largely by this influx of money supplies rather than the increased productivity of the economy?